# Events between sibling components in Vue.js, why register them on the $root?

Tags: vue.js, state-management

I was just going through some Vue.js code [here](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/develop/website/client/components/challenges/challengeModal.vue#L244) and noticed some code inside a modal component that looks like so:

```
mounted () {
  this.$root.$on('habitica:update-challenge', (data) => {
    if (!data.challenge) return;
    this.cloning = false;
    this.$store.state.challengeOptions.workingChallenge = Object.assign({}, this.$store.state.challengeOptions.workingChallenge, data.challenge);
    this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', 'challenge-modal');
  });
}
```

If you move to a line in s sibling component [here](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/develop/website/client/components/challenges/challengeDetail.vue#L66), you basically see a sibling component calling a `edit()` function which is basically just the below:

```
edit () {
  this.$root.$emit('habitica:update-challenge', {
    challenge: this.challenge,
  });
}
```

So if I am right the event is being registered on the `this.$root` component inside `challengeModal` and then is being inside `challenDetail` component using `this.$root.$emit`? Is my analogy right on this?

A few secondary questions: is `challenge: this.challenge,` a payload that's being sent to the `this.$root` and is `challenge: this.challenge,` being received inside `this.$root.$on('habitica:update-challenge', (data) => {` in the form of an argument namely `data` ?

P.S. I'm coming from a ReactJS/jQuery background so just trying to wrap my head around Vue events.

Comment: yes. yes. yes. yes.

Comment: As for jQuery, it would be the same there. `on` and `off` method naming originates from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct.

Vue events were borrowed from AngularJS, event API changed further in Vue 2. The concept is [similar](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Programmatic-Event-Listeners) to DOM or other JavaScript event implementations:

> Note that Vue’s event system is different from the browser’s EventTarget API. Though they work similarly, $emit, $on, and $off are not aliases for dispatchEvent, addEventListener, and removeEventListener.

Siblings should communicate through common parent, `$root` instance acts as global event bus. Event listener is registered inside one component and is triggered inside another one.